# How do I go about installing a Bitcoin daemon in CentOS Linux?

Tags: commerce, ecommerce

I am trying to setup [a Drupal e-commerce solution](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_bitcoin) with a payment gateway of accepting Bitcoins during checkout, but I need a bitcoin daemon installed. How do I go about installing the Bitcoin daemon in my [CentOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) installation?

Is there a step-by-step guide on what I need to type to install this? It would be great if it can be installed via a package manager in CentOS. [apt-get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool) doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: You'll want to find a `yum` repository that has `bitcoind` in it, as CentOS uses YUM and not APT.

Comment: If you would like to build from source: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/30106/19021

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I host two `bitcoind` RPMs (i686, x86_64) on my website which will most likely work fine for you, as they're built for CentOS 6.4. Run this command to install `bitcoind` :

```
rpm -ivh http://tvdw.eu/bitcoin-0.8.1-1.el6.`uname -m`.rpm
```

If you want to download them manually, the files are:

```
i686:   http://tvdw.eu/bitcoin-0.8.1-1.el6.i686.rpm
MD5:    5be52618594a3eaded19052197c2f6ed

x86_64: http://tvdw.eu/bitcoin-0.8.1-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
MD5:    49ba4acbf9744e96bf12342888bc347a
```

The packages are unsigned, so install these at your own risk (aka: some level of trust is required here).

[Edit] This is the `bitcoin.spec` file I use to build these packages :

```
Name:           bitcoin
Version:        0.8.1
Release:        1%{?dist}
Summary:        bitcoin

License:        GPL
URL:            http://bitcoin.org
Source0:        http://sourceforge.net/projects/bitcoin/files/Bitcoin/bitcoin-%{version}/bitcoin-%{version}-linux.tar.gz

%description
bitcoin

%package qt
Summary:        bitcoin-qt
%description qt
bitcoin-qt


%prep
%setup -q -n bitcoin-%{version}-linux


%build


%install
mkdir -p %{buildroot}%{_bindir}
%ifarch x86_64
cp -R bin/64/* %{buildroot}%{_bindir}
%endif
%ifarch i686
cp -R bin/32/* %{buildroot}%{_bindir}
%endif


%clean
rm -rf %{buildroot}


%files
%doc README COPYING
/usr/bin/bitcoind

%files qt
/usr/bin/bitcoin-qt


%changelog
```

There's no actual compilation involved, it just puts the files in the right locations and wraps it in a nice little RPM.

Comment: there is no way to install the same ones from the main bitcoin site? Yes a level of trust is indeed needed. but for the sake of the paranoid user, how can one do it themselves.

Comment: @duckx I updated my answer with the `bitcoin.spec` file I use to build the packages.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [this setup](http://www.ringingliberty.com/bitcoin/), by another fellow [StackExchange member](https://stackexchange.com/users/1068389/michael-hampton).

Or you might want to take the **easier route and use a [Bitcoin Payment Gateway](https://bitpay.com)**.

Answer (score 0):

Don't trust just any source. People smarter than me strongly recommend using the official builds from bitcoincore.org. On CentOS, I've had success using the [official](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/packaging) [snap package](https://snapcraft.io/install/bitcoin-core/centos), and I've copied the instructions below:

```
yum -y install epel-release
yum -y install snapd
systemctl enable --now snapd.socket
ln -s /var/lib/snapd/snap /snap
snap install bitcoin-core
```

PS: Use `bitcoin-core.cli` and `bitcoin-core.deamon` as commands.

PPS: You might need to run these commands as a super user (e.g. using `sudo`).