# Use multiple GPU's with oclvanitygen

Tags: vanitygen

Does anyone know how to use multiple GPU's with `oclvanitygen`? I have these two:

```
Available OpenCL platforms:
0: [Intel(R) Corporation] Intel(R) OpenCL
  0: [Intel(R) Corporation]       Intel(R)
  1: [Intel(R) Corporation] Intel(R) HD Gra
1: [NVIDIA Corporation] NVIDIA CUDA
  0: [NVIDIA Corporation] GeForce GT 630M
```

What would be the command for using both of them if I want an address that starts with `1MYbtc`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 -D 0:0 -D 0:1 -D 0:2  (etc for as many GPUs as you have)
```

Edit:  Sorry I'll clarify for future users..

```
 ./oclvanitygen -i 1address
```

gets me..

```
 Available OpenCL platforms:
 0: [Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.] AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
 0: [Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.] Tahiti
 1: [Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.] Tahiti
 2: [AuthenticAMD] AMD FX(tm)-4130 Quad-Core Processor
```

So if I want to use the 2x GPU but not the CPU then I'll run..

```
 ./oclvanitygen -i 1address -D 0:0 -D 0:1
```

or if I want to only use the CPU then I'll do..

```
 ./oclvanitygen -i 1address -D 0:2
```

(yes you can use multiple processes so I could mine one address with one GPU and another with the other GPU)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I was interested after your previous question, and tried to install it myself. Unfortunately I keep getting the

```
  vanitygen: pattern.c:164: vg_exec_context_init: Assertion `vxcp->vxc_key' failed.
```

error, and I have no sudo-rights to fix it right now.

However, to fix your problem, it runs on CPU, not GPU. And it already uses all  CPU's, according to the README. If you have a quad-core CPU there will be 4 workers who have ~100% CPU each. If you want to limit the amount of CPU's used, use the `-t <threads>`-option.

Comment: Hey sorry, I meant OCLvanitygen.

Comment: Oh crap. I didn't knew that also existed

Comment: if anyone still getting this error, check these https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/24364/how-do-i-use-vanitygen-on-fedora-20-openssl-restrictions  https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=641328.0

Answer (score 0):

on Windows for example:

```
oclvanitygen.exe -D 1:0 1YourName
```